# how to use full height of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the full height of the webpage. However, it only uses like 40% of the webpage's height. So, I looked up online and it said that I should use HTML, body {height: 100%}. So I used HTML, body {height: 100%} but it doesn't work. I tried to give 20% to header, 70% to section, and 10% to footer. However, I didn't do it because if I do that, my text won't vertically center. How can I do it?

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 0;
    }
    
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }


    header{
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 30px 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
     

    section {
        display: flex;
       
    }
   
    nav, article {
        border: solid 1px black;
        clear: both;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    nav {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: darkslateblue;
    }

    article {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        flex: 4;
    }

    footer {
        border: solid 1px black;
        background-color: crimson;
        padding: 10px;
        
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>hello!</header>
<section>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <h2>hello</h2>
        <p>hello how are you?</p>
    </article>
</section>
<footer>this is footer</footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `vh` relative unit. `vh` stands for Viewport Height and can be used like so:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This will tell the browser to use **100%** of the **viewport height**. There is also a `vw`, which controls the width relative to the viewport.

Read more on relative units on the [MDN page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

I'd recommend using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to create your layout. Combine it with the `100vh` to first make your layout full height, and then divide the elements within it by creating a grid.

Look at the example below, specifically the CSS part. In there you see `grid-template-rows` where we define three rows of 20%, 70% and 10% height. Thats, 20, 70 and 10 percent of the `100vh` to divide.

With `grid-template-areas` we can name our rows and columns. Later on we need to tell the grid children *where* in the grid they are supposed to go. By naming our cells, we only have to reference the name of the cell at each child (see `grid-area` in the CSS).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 70% 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "main"
    "footer";
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: blue;
}

.grid-main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.grid-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<body class="grid">
  <header class="grid-header"></header>
  <main class="grid-main"></main>
  <footer class="grid-footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Alternatively you could divide your three main sections into `20vh`, `70vh` and `10vh` sections.

Comment: He alsos want to set the height for the footer, header and main content. So he will also need to use `vh`for doing that.

Comment: @FrancoPan gotcha! I've added a snippet which solves this.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Do you have any idea how you can put vertically and horizontally centered  <h1> in the blue area (.grid-header)? when I put text-aling: center, it only centers horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code for the `body`:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

You can learn more about units here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here. I think they want the footer at the bottom.

Comment: So he can just use `100vh` for `section`. Then the footer will be on the bottom of the page

Comment: But that will make the whole page larger than the viewport. It will scroll vertically even though the content would fit without scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, so use can use smaller value insted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! However,  do you have any idea how you can put vertically and horizontally centered <h1> in the blue area? when I put text-aling: center, it only centers horizontally –

Answer (score 0):

Set the heights for the header, section and footer with height: ...vh.

vh is the shortcut for viewport height.

```
...
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}

section {
    height: 70vh;
    display: flex;  
 }

footer {
    height: 10vh;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: crimson;
    padding: 10px;       
    text-align: center;
 }
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  However,  do you have any idea how you can put vertically and horizontally centered <h1> in the blue area? when I put text-aling: center, it only centers horizontally –

Comment: No problem. Yes to center your <h1> vertically use align-items: center; to center horizontally use justify-content: center; and then you must set your header to display: flex; I have the code updated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a wrapper would solve the problem! The final code is like below:

```html
<style>
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 0;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      height:100%;
      flex-direction: column;
  }

.wrapper > *{
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
}
  header{
      background-color: blue;
      padding: 30px 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
   
  nav, article {
      border: solid 1px black;
      clear: both;
      background-color: aqua;
  }

  nav {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: darkslateblue;
  }

  article {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      flex: 4;
  }

  footer {
      border: solid 1px black;
      background-color: crimson;
      padding: 10px;
      
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>hello!</header>
<section>
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <p>hello how are you?</p>
  </article>
</section>
<footer>this is footer</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However,  do you have any idea how you can put vertically and horizontally centered <h1> in the blue area? when I put text-aling: center, it only centers horizontally –